# Scrapy-Splash doesn't set custom request headers

Tags: python, header, request, scrapy, splash-screen

I am trying to scrape a website using Scrapy + Splash in Python 2.7. 
The website uses JavaScript to generate most of the HTML, which is why I need Splash.

First, I make a FormRequest with Scrapy to login to a website. It is successful.

I then extract "access_token" from JSON response, because it should be used in the next request as an "Authorization" header - to confirm to the website that I am logged in.

```
jsonresp = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
self.token = 'Bearer ' + jsonresp['access_token']
self.my_headers['Authorization'] = self.token
```

Before proceeding with SplashRequest, I decided to test the session with **scrapy.Request**. I passed cookies and the new headers:

```
 yield scrapy.Request('https://www.example.com/products', cookies=self.cookies, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_pages,  headers=self.my_headers)
```

The HTML from result.body confirmed that I was logged in. Great!

Calling *response.request.headers* showed that 'Authorization' header was also sent.

```
{'Accept-Language': ['en-US,en;q=0.5'], 
'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip,deflate'], 
'Accept': ['application/json, text/plain, */*'], 
'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'], 
'Connection': ['keep-alive'], 
'Referer': ['https://www.example.com/Web'], 
'Cookie': ["___cookies___"], 
'Content-Type': ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], 
'Authorization': ['Bearer Zyb9c20JW0LLJCTA-GmLtEeL9A48se_AviN9xajP8NZVE8r6TddoPHC6dJnmbQ4RCddM8QVJ2v23ey-kq5f8S12uLMXlLF_WzInNI9eaI29WAcIwNK-FixBpDm4Ws3SqXdwBIXfkqYhd6gJs4BP7sNpAKc93t-A4ws9ckpTyih2cHeC8KGQmTnQXLOYch2XIyT5r9verzRMMGHEiu6kgJWK9yRL19PVqCWDjapYbtutKiTRKD1Q35EHjruBJgJD-Fg_iyMovgYkfy9XtHpAEuUvL_ascWHWvrFQqV-19p-6HQPocEuri0Vu0NsAqutfIbi420_zhD8sDFortDmacltNOw-3f6H1imdGstXE_2GQ']}
```

Cookie DEBUG showed that all cookies were sent without issues.

After that I substituted scrapy.Request with **SplashRequest**:

```
yield SplashRequest('https://www.example.com/products', cookies=self.cookies,  callback=self.parse_pages, args={"lua_source": lua_script, 'headers':self.my_headers},  endpoint='execute', errback=self.errors)
```

lua_script:

```
lua_script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  assert(splash:go{
    splash.args.url,
    headers=splash.args.headers,
    http_method=splash.args.http_method,
    body=splash.args.body,
  })
  assert(splash:wait(2))

  local entries = splash:history()
  local last_response = entries[#entries].response

  return {
    url = splash:url(),
    headers = last_response.headers,
    http_status = last_response.status,
    html = splash:html(),
    }
end
"""
```

However, the HTML that I got from Splash response showed that I was **not logged in**.

Cookie DEBUG didn't show any issues - the same cookies were sent as before.

But here is what I got from calling *response.request.headers*:

```
 {'Accept-Language': ['en'], 
'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip,deflate'], 
'Accept': ['text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'], 
'User-Agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'], 
'Cookie': ["___cokies___"], 
'Content-Type': ['application/json']}
```

As you can see, Splash didn't set my custom headers, instead it just combined cookies with the default ones.

I tried setting my own headers both as SplashRequest function arguments and inside lua_script, but none of the approaches worked.

My question is, how to set my own **request headers** in Splash?